# Default user: WSO2 Identity Server with Mariadb

Tags: mariadb, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I followed the steps defined in [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Setting+up+MySQL) link and restarted the WSO2 identity server.

When trying to login at https://localhost:9443/carbon using admin/admin credentials, it's giving me login failed message. Before changing the settings for WSO2, it was working with this credentials.

Obviously, that user is not present in MariaDB. Does anyone has any scripts to insert an admin user in WSO2 Maria DB for? I don't know what all tables I need to update in case of adding user manually. Or is there any other default user?

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem, even switched to mysql community and it didn't fix it.
So with mysql installed I did the following, after MANY tries,
`mysql -u root -p`
`create DATABASE regdb;` 
`exit;`
`mysql -u root -p regdb < <WSO2_HOME>/dbscripts/mysql5.7.sql`
`mysql -u root -p regdb < <WSO2_HOME>/dbscripts/identity/mysql-5.7.sql`
`nohup <WSO2_HOME>/bin/wso2server.h -Dsetup &`
If there is someplace to see the DB version, I haven't found it, but this got it all to working form me.  So loading keep failing the DB because of some default time functions in the sql.
My $0.02